# Reraise (same exception) after catching an exception in Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

I am trying to improve my Ruby skills by catching exceptions. I want to know if it is common to reraise the same kind of exception when you have several method calls. So, would the following code make sense? Is it ok to reraise the same kind of exception, or should I not catch it on the process method?

```
class Logo
  def process
    begin
      @processed_logo = LogoProcessor::create_image(self.src)
    rescue CustomException
      raise CustomException
    end
  end
end

module LogoProcessor
  def self.create_image
    raise CustomException if some_condition
  end
end
```

Comment: cannot we just `rescue CustomException => e; raise e` ?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Sometimes we just want to know an error *happened*, without having to actually *handle* the error.

It is often the case that the one responsible for handling errors is user of the object: the caller. What if we are interested in the error, but don't want to assume that responsibility? We rescue the error, do whatever we need to do and then propagate the signal up the stack as if nothing had happened.

For example, what if we wanted to log the error message and then let the caller deal with it?

```
begin
  this_will_fail!
rescue Failure => error
  log.error error.message
  raise
end
```

**Calling [`raise`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) without any arguments will raise the last error.** In our case, we are re-raising `error`.

In the example you presented in your question, re-raising the error is simply not necessary. You could simply let it propagate up the stack naturally. The only difference in your example is you're creating a new error object and raising it instead of re-raising the last one.

Comment: Interesting. My question is, if I don't catch the error in the definition of process, then I would need to catch it when I call the process method, e.g: ``begin @logo.process; rescue...``, but then I wouldn't be catching an exception launched by process itself, but of something that has been called from within process. Is that correct to do?

Comment: This would loose the `stacktrace` from the original exception, you probably want to include exception `cause` which is available in ruby > 2.1

Comment: @bjhaid Calling `raise` in the manner of this answer preserves the original exception entirely, including the `backtrace`. `cause` does not apply to this case. Rather, it gets populated automatically when a `rescue` block raises a new exception.

Comment: @HommerSmith : What if the line before raise (log.error in this case, but it could be anything) fails? I'm thinking on "ensuring" it, but, inside the ensure I would need to use the reference to the error as the argument of "raise". What do you think about that?

Comment: Is that behavior of preserving the backtrace documented somewhere? I couldn't find much about it in the docs. https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html

Comment: FYI for other people wondering `raise error` seems to be equivalent to just doing `raise`. I thought that these two are different for some reason – and they would be if I was raising a new error object, but both cases reuse the current error.

Comment: @RafałCieślak Every time an error is raised, it is assigned to the `$!` global variable. Calling `raise` without arguments raises the error contained in `$!`, effectively raising the last error. However, `raise error` will raise the error contained in the `error` local variable, which may or may not be the same object contained in `$!`. In my example, `$!` is the same as `error`. However, it's also possible to do this: `error = Exception.new; raise error`

Comment: @RafałCieślak it's not quite as simple as `Every time an error is raised, it is assigned to the $! global variable`; I posted a full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69652924)

Comment: @user2426679 You're correct. It turns out `$!` is not a true global variable. It will always refer to the exception currently being handled and only exists inside the block that's handling it. Thank you for teaching me this! [Here's a demonstration on ideone.](https://ideone.com/Kc8yzP)

Comment: @RafałCieślak Yes, it is documented in [`Exception#cause`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Exception.html#method-i-cause) which says the method will return "the previous exception (`$!`) at the time this exception was raised".

Answer (score 6):

This will raise the same type of error as the original, but you can customize the message.

```
rescue StandardError => e
  raise e.class, "Message: #{e.message}"
```

Comment: I would suggest its a bad idea to catch StandardError as this includes all kinds of lower level functions and could hang your program.

Comment: I believe this is an "exception" to the rule, since we're immediately raising the Exception again.

Comment: I see what you did there, @FreePender ;)

Comment: I know it's been a year, but it's safe to catch StandardError, @PaulWhitehead -- it's Exception you must never, ever catch.  (Quick source: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/rescue-standarderror-not-exception )

Comment: Actually the `Exception` class has an `exception` method which allows to do exactly that. See my answer.

Comment: This makes debugging more difficult because

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question as in the comment thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770924/reraise-same-exception-after-catching-an-exception-in-ruby#comment102291341_23771227), i.e. `What if the line before (re)raise fails?`

My understanding was limited by the missing knowledge that the global variable of `$!` is "kinda garbage collected" // "scoped to its functional context", which the below example demonstrates:

```
def func
  begin
    raise StandardError, 'func!'
  rescue StandardError => err
    puts "$! = #{$!.inspect}"
  end
end

begin
  raise StandardError, 'oh no!'
rescue StandardError => err
  func
  puts "$! = #{$!.inspect}"
  raise
end
```

The output of the above is:

```
$! = #<StandardError: func!>
$! = #<StandardError: oh no!>
StandardError: oh no!
from (pry):47:in `__pry__'
```

This behavior is different than how Python's `(re)raise` works.

[The documentation for `Exception`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Exception.html) states:

> When an exception has been raised but not yet handled (in `rescue`,
> `ensure`, `at_exit` and `END` blocks), two global variables are set:
>
> - `$!` contains the current exception.
> - `$@` contains its backtrace.

So these variables aren't true global variables, they are only defined inside the block that's handling the error.

```
begin
  raise
rescue
  p $!  # StandardError
end

p $!    # nil
```

Comment: You're right! It turns out `$!` and `$@` aren't true global variables. They're only defined in `rescue`, `ensure`, `at_exit` and `END` blocks. Thank you for teaching me something today!

Answer (score 4):

A slightly better way to do the same thing [as FreePender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57386433/4575793) is to use the `exception` method from the `Exception` class, which is the ancestor class to any error classes, like `StandardError`, so that the method is available to any error classes.

Here the method's documentation that you can find on [ApiDock](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_6_3/Exception/exception):

> With no argument, or if the argument is the same as the receiver, return the receiver. Otherwise, create a new exception object of the same class as the receiver, but with a message equal to string.to_str.

Now let's see how it works:

```rb
begin
  this_will_fail!
rescue Failure => error
  raise error.exception("Message: #{error.message}")
end
```

Comment: Note that it won't always work. For example, the `Timeout::Error` has this method overriden and it ignores the args.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to above answers here:

- In some applications you may need to log the error twice.
- For example exception need to be notified to monitoring tools like
  Nagios/Newrelic/Cloudwatch.
- At the same time you may have your own kibana backed summary logging
  tool, internally for your reference.

In those cases you might want to log & handle the errors multiple times.

**Example:**

```
begin
  begin
    nil.to_sym
  rescue => e
    puts "inner block error message: #{e.message}"
    puts "inner block backtrace: #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
    raise e
  end
rescue => e
  puts "outer block error message: #{e.message}"
  puts "outer block backtrace: #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
end
```

> I am using puts here, for your the ease of verifying this code in
> rails console, in actual production you may need to use rails logger