# Can you rescue from specific errors with messages in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand how errors propogate between classes in Ruby. I have this so far:

```
class User
  def charge
    puts "charging order soon"
    raise RuntimeError.new("This is a runtime error")
  rescue ArgumentError
    puts "should never gets here"
  end
end

class Runner
  def run
    begin
      User.new.charge
    rescue RuntimeError => e
      puts e.message
    end
  end
end

Runner.new.run
```

When I run this, I get this which seems right:

```
$ ruby errors.rb
charging order soon
This is a runtime error
```

Inside runner, can I rescue from the `RuntimeError` with a specific message? If I have multiple `RuntimeErrors` being raised around my application, is there any way for the Runner's rescue clause to be raised only for RuntimeErrors with specific messages?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23771227/2981429

If you call `raise` inside a rescue block, the last raised exception will be re-raised.

In your exception block, you can check the message and choose to re-raise or not:

```
begin
  User.new.charge
rescue RuntimeError => e
  case e.message
  when "This is a runtime error"
    # put your handler code here
  else
    raise # re-raise the last exception
  end
end
```

However if it's your goal to solely rescue errors that you yourself raise manually, then it's probably easier to define a custom error class instead:

```
class MyError < StandardError; end
```

Then instead of `raise RuntimeError.new("message")` use `raise MyError.new("message")`, and rescue it normally:

```
begin
  User.new.charge
rescue MyError => e
  # handler
end
```

This way you don't have to worry about your rescues interfering with the built-in exceptions.

Comment: Could you explain why the docs suggest to create a subclass of `StandardError` and then have specific exception types inherit from it. I don't really get why we would do this: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Exception.html

Comment: @Jwan622 sorry I didn't respond to this for 1.5 years but by inheriting from StandardError you get all the built in behavior of that class, with the benefit of the ability to be specific about what error you're rescuing. It's better to use a custom error class than a built in error class, so you don't accidentally rescue something else.