# Raising another error from a rescue block emits the original error that brought us into the rescue block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, exception, runtime-error

## **The case**

I have a Rail 4 application controller with a `index` method in it like this:

```
def index
  raise "Original Error"
rescue => e
  puts "We caught: '#{e.inspect}'"
  raise "Another Error"
end
```

I am catching the `Original Error`, handling it, massaging it, doing whatever i want it, and then throwing a **completely different** error out -  `Another Error`.

---

## The expectation

It is, therefore, expected that my Rails app will produce `Another Error` when i visit the index page of controller and not the `Original Error`.

---

## **The unexpected behavior**

But i am actually getting the `Original Error` instead. Copying the logs of the controller#action here:

```
Started GET "/homepage" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-06 18:50:19 +0800
We caught: '#<RuntimeError: Original Error>'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 205ms (Flexirest: 0.0ms for 0 calls | ActiveRecord: 9.7ms)

RuntimeError - Original Error:
  app/controllers/homepage_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

Why is it throwing the `Original Error` here instead of the `Another Error`?

---

## However, the behavior in the console is still as expected

I copy-pasted the same `index` method lines into my Rails console and then called the `index` method directly from within the console. Here is the console output for that.

```
[49] pry(main)> def index
[49] pry(main)*   raise "Original Error"
[49] pry(main)* rescue => e
[49] pry(main)*   puts "We caught: '#{e.inspect}'"
[49] pry(main)*   raise "Another Error"
[49] pry(main)* end
=> :index

[50] pry(main)> index
We caught: '#<RuntimeError: Original Error>'
RuntimeError: Another Error
from (pry):67:in `rescue in index'
[51] pry(main)>
```

---

## ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: when i try to reproduce it in rails 5 server logs the both the exceptions.

Comment: i am using rails 4. BTW... i updated the post with **"Another difference in observation in the Rails console"**

Comment: @SyedRakibAlHasan It's quite weird behavior, could you try to log from rescue and see if it still raises an error along with logging ?

Comment: Also, this might help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770924/reraise-same-exception-after-catching-an-exception-in-ruby

Comment: @zauzaj that article is about re-raising the same error. I am not trying to re-raise the same error here. Just trying to throw a new/different error when we catch the original error

Answer (score 2):

Since Ruby 2.1 the `Kernel#raise` method has a default parameter for `cause` that's using the "ambient exception" `$!`:

```rb
  raise(string, cause: $!)
```

The effect is that every exception raised while in a scope of an ambient exception (i.e. in a `rescue` block) will populate the `cause` attribute of the raised exception with the current exception, unless the caller specifies a different value for `cause` during `raise`.

Your webserver/middleware is probably digging up the `cause` chain to find the "root cause" error and showing that one, probably using something like `e = e.cause until e.cause.nil?`.

If you want to suppress this behavior you can specify `nil` as the `cause` during `raise`:

```rb
raise "Another Error", cause: nil
```